# I want a python code to obtain the unique genres

Tags: python, pandas

I only want to obtain the unique genres of the movies, thanks
[Data base shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOT7u.png)
[Link to the data base:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rGujThG8_6RVMoUEF-nDyET5bZv-hMWp/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Convert strings repr to lists and then use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
import ast

L = df['genres'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().unique().tolist()
```

Alternative:

```
L = df['genres'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s+').explode().unique().tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` may be overkill if you're not going to do more with this information~

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain
import csv

with open('genres.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    values = [literal_eval(x[0]) for x in reader]

unique = set(chain.from_iterable(values))
print(unique)
```

Output:

```
{'action',
 'animation',
 'comedy',
 'crime',
 'documentation',
 'drama',
 'european',
 'family',
 'fantasy',
 'history',
 'horror',
 'music',
 'reality',
 'romance',
 'scifi',
 'sport',
 'thriller',
 'war',
 'western'}
```